# Display image in listview using simpleAdapter ANDROID

Tags: java, android, listview, simpleadapter

I am currently working on an android application displaying image into my listview using SimpleAdapter. My image is retrieved from my online server. After i retrieve the image, i tried to display the image but nothing was displayed and no error too.

**Below is my code**

```
class ListApplicant extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpApplicantActivity.this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    // getting All applicants from URL
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", eid));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_list_applicant,
                "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All applicants: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // applicants found
                // Getting Array of applicants
                applicant = json.getJSONArray(TAG_APPLICANTS);

                // looping through All applicants
                for (int i = 0; i < applicant.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = applicant.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each JSON item in variable
                    String uid = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String overall = c.getString(TAG_OVERALL);
                    String apply_datetime = c.getString(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    // HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,
                    // String>();

                    // IMAGE HASHMAP
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key (value)
                    map.put(TAG_UID, uid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_OVERALL, overall);
                    map.put(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, apply_datetime);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    // applicantsList.add(map);

                    // LISTING IMAGE TO LISTVIEW
                    try {
                        imageURL = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(
                                "http://ec2-175-41-164-218.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/android/images/"
                                        + imageURL).getContent();
                        d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    map.put(TAG_PHOTO, d.toString());

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    applicantsList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all applicants
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (applicantsList.isEmpty()) {
                    applicantDisplay
                            .setText("No applicants have signed up yet");
                } else {

                    //Updating parsed JSON data into ListView

                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            SignUpApplicantActivity.this, applicantsList,
                            R.layout.list_applicant, new String[] {
                                    TAG_UID, TAG_NAME, TAG_OVERALL,
                                    TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, TAG_PHOTO },
                            new int[] { R.id.applicantUid,
                                    R.id.applicantName,
                                    R.id.applicantOverall,
                                    R.id.apply_datetime, R.id.list_image });
                    // updating listView
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to save the image first instead of creating a drawable directly from the InputStream, and see if that makes any difference

Comment: where can i save the image too?

Comment: There was no error because you wrapped a lot of codes in try...catch block. There was probably no image because there was no JSON to begin with. What about you use httpGet to get the response string and then you try building a JSONObject from it. In any case 1)Check the response for valid JSON format 2)Check the parsed response for missing JSON paramters. EDIT:3) And use debug mode

Comment: probably you may use a sdcard if you get one or two images else use the concept of lazy loading

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
map.put(TAG_PHOTO, d.toString());
```

You set that key to a string like `"Drawable@0x12345678"` and then bind it to `R.id.list_image` which I assume is an ImageView.  That won't work.

I haven't used a Drawable quite like that, but I have had success with a Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

And then I overrode `bindView` on my Adapter to set the image:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // do the default stuff
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    // now set the image
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

A `SimpleAdapter` doesn't have a `bindView` method, so instead you can provide a `ViewBinder`:

```
mySimpleAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
        if (view.getId().equals(R.id.my_img_view_id)) {
            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // we have successfully bound this view
            return true;
        } else {
            // allow default binding to occur
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: oohh. sorry. im new to android and im stuck in this issue for weeks. For your suggestion, i will give it a try to see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: how do i override the bindView to my simpleadapter?

Comment: I believe this works for `SimpleCursorAdapter` and not for `SimpleAdapter`. I found this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) which shows that these methods work for `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: @SarahPhil I think you can Override it by just adding `@Override` just above the start of the method so like `@Override                                      public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
 }`